# NPM RangeError ERR_INVALID_ASYNC_ID Invalid triggerAsyncId when install nodejs 12.6.0 in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm facing a problem when I install Nodejs v12.6.0 in Windows 10 Pro. I can get the version of Node normally, but when I run the command to get the version of NPM, it gives me an error. Then I cannot run my Node application in this machine because of this error.

```
// This is ok
C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v12.6.0

// But this gives me an error like below
C:\Windows\System32>npm -v
RangeError [ERR_INVALID_ASYNC_ID]: Invalid asyncId value: 27
    at validateAsyncId (internal/async_hooks.js:119:16)
    at emitAfterScript (internal/async_hooks.js:360:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:7)
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-10T04_26_39_285Z-debug.log
6.9.0
```

And log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'prefix',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.6.0
4 timing npm Completed in 201ms
5 error cb() never called!
6 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
7 error <https://npm.community>
```

I also reinstalled Node and Windows OS, but this issue is not fixed.
Please help me.

Comment: please install the latest stable version of node or reinstall npm. That should fix let me know what happened. cheers!

Comment: @BPDESILVA I installed nodejs stable (v10.16.0), then delete npm and install npm 6.10.0, but it still happens the issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out my problem, that was about CPU. It did not work fine, something was wrong in Windows 64-bit platform (a few of other 64-bit software worked not so well also). And then, I had to replace a new CPU and now the error above disappears.

Hope this information can help somebody.